# Java 2D - Vertically centering text

Tags: java, swing, graphics, fonts, java-2d

The problem I am facing is, that the descent that I get from a font metrics object seems to be incorrect. This is only noticable on very big fonts. I already tried using the `FontMetrics#getDescent`-method and the `FontMetrics#getStringBounds`-Method of which i then used `height` and `y` to manually make out the descent. While both give a slightly different result, both are incorrect. What is the most correct way to get a correct baseline for a pre-defined set of characters? In my case it'd be the characters `0-9`. These should all have the same baseline and therefore be easy to center. So my assumption at least.

Here's an example showcasing the problem:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class Draw
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add( new X() );
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize( 150, 300 );
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    frame.setVisible( true );
  }

  private static class X extends JComponent
  {
    private final Font xFont;

    public X()
    {
      xFont = UIManager.getFont( "Label.font" ).deriveFont( 40.0f );
    }

    @Override
    public void paint( Graphics g )
    {
      g.setColor( Color.YELLOW );
      g.fillRect( 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );

      g.setColor( Color.BLACK );
      g.drawLine( 0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() / 2 );

      g.setFont( xFont );
      g.drawString( "X", getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2 + g.getFontMetrics().getDescent() );
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

The black line represents the middle of the component. The vertical center of the `X` should be aligned with the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work even with large fonts.  The adjustment was to subtract both the `leading` and the `descent` from the `ascent` and divide by two. It would seem if you don't include the leading, the text drifts for large fonts. In this example, the font size is `300`.  For smaller fonts, it may not be a problem.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(),
            getHeight() / 2);
    g.setFont(xFont);
    String s = "X";
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    int swidth = fm.stringWidth(s);

    int ctrx = getWidth() / 2;
    int ctry = getHeight() / 2;

    int mheight = fm.getAscent() - fm.getDescent() - fm.getLeading();

    g.drawString(s, ctrx - swidth/2, ctry + mheight/2);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see. Guess I should've taken a closer look at the documentation. It says `The height metric is calculated to include this extra space.`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want:

```
  FontMetrics fm =  g.getFontMetrics();
  g.drawString( "X", getWidth() / 2, (getHeight() + fm.getAscent() - fm.getDescent())/2 );
```

Which gives:

[image]